# multiple logistic regression - relative change in the predicted probabilities with unbalanced classes

Tags: probability, logistic, multiple-regression, interaction, unbalanced-classes

I have a multiple logistic regression with continuous variables (dist_fs, slope, min_dist), one binary variable (exp), and one interaction between the binary variable and a continuous variable. The response variable is not balanced, I have n=273 for "1" and n=13847 for "0".

The summary of the model provided these coefficients:

```
Fixed effects:
                     Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)          -3.25942    0.24478 -13.316  < 2e-16 ***
dist_fs              -1.95321    0.83374  -2.343  0.01914 *  
slope                -0.01183    0.42595  -0.028  0.97785    
min_dist             -0.67566    0.43925  -1.538  0.12399    
exp1                 -1.25486    0.23607  -5.316 1.06e-07 ***
dist_fs:exp1          3.97196    1.26526   3.139  0.00169 **
```

Using `plot_model()` I obtained this plot for the interaction:

[image]

**My question:**

I understand that the low predicted probabilities may come from the unbalanced sample size of the response variable. But I see that the difference between the probabilities of the binary variable is very small (~2-3%, when x=0).

If the sample size would be balanced, and the trends similar, could we expect the difference in the % between the two categories to be different as well (that is, also higher)? Or this difference would be the same, independently of the balanced/unbalanced sample size? Or we can't conclude anything about this, without a balanced dataset?

Thanks in advance for any thoughts on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thinking in terms of percentage-point differences can lead to confusion in logistic regression. The coefficients are in units of log-odds differences associated with the predictor values. Those aren't linearly related to percentage values.

The negative intercept in your model is related to the low overall probability of the `used` outcome in your data. If your data adequately represent the underlying population of interest, that's what you should focus on.

If there were simply an under-representation of cases with `used` outcomes and the regression coefficients still represented the correct differences in log-odds associated with changing predictor values, then you could estimate corresponding percentage-point differences. With your current intercept of `-3.259`, the percentage estimates with all continuous predictors at 0 for the two levels of the binary `exp` predictor are about 3.7% and 1.1%; if the data had been better "balanced" so that intercept was `0` and the other coefficients were the same, those percentages would be about 50% and 22%, respectively.

```
plogis(-3.259)
# [1] 0.03700483
plogis(-3.259-1.255)
# [1] 0.01083585
plogis(0)
# [1] 0.5
plogis(0-1.255)
# [1] 0.2218358
```

That said, it seems unlikely that a "better balanced" data set would only change the intercept of the model without affecting the other coefficient estimates.

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful. Just to then make it clear, basically what you're saying is that I can't really assume anything regarding the changes in the predicted probabilities, right? I would have to change the binary response variable to see how the intercept, coefficients, and predicted probs change?

Comment: @mtao that's correct, to get into the probability scale you have to work with the coefficients in their log-odds scales first, then at the very last step convert to a probability scale.